# Date query not bringing back correct results

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm querying a set of dates and am not having success with returning results from the past week. So from (current date - 7 days) to present.

These are the sets of dates:

```
2013-12-19 17:30:23.153
2013-12-13 00:00:00.000
2013-12-19 00:00:00.000
2013-11-19 00:00:00.000
2013-12-19 00:00:00.000
2013-12-19 00:00:00.000
2013-12-19 00:00:00.000
2013-12-15 00:00:00.000
2013-12-20 12:42:59.223
2013-12-20 12:45:17.713
2013-12-20 13:10:02.797
```

(11 in total. 1 previous month. 10 current month. 8 in the past week.)

C#:

```
query.Where(c => c.CreatedOn > System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(c.CreatedOn, -7)).Count();
```

Converted SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[EmailLinkClickId] AS [EmailLinkClickId], 
[Extent1].[EmailLinkId] AS [EmailLinkId], 
[Extent1].[MailingListRecipientId] AS [MailingListRecipientId], 
[Extent1].[CampaignId] AS [CampaignId], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[IPAddress] AS [IPAddress]
FROM [Marketing].[dbo].[EmailLinkClick] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  CAST( [Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS datetime2) > (DATEADD (day, -7, [Extent1].[CreatedOn]))
```

The problem is that both of these queries just return the full data set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks all. Sometimes just takes an extra eye to notice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the date to the date-7 instead of present-7:

```
query.Where(c => c.CreatedOn > System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(c.CreatedOn, -7)).Count();
```

Try this:

```
query.Where(c => c.CreatedOn > System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -7)).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You did the calculation relative to the date in the database. You need it relative to current date:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
query.Where(c => c.CreatedOn > startDate).Count();
```

To be independent from time:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
```

*Comment: I'm using `startDate` because I think there is no need letting the database do the calculation, although there is nothing wrong with using `DbFunctions`.*

Answer (score 0):

Your query is looking for dates which are greater than seven days ago. You will also need to restrict so it only returns dates also less than today's date.

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
query.Where(c => c.CreatedOn > startDate && c.CreatedOn < DateTime.Now).Count();
```

although your test data does not show any dates in the future...